# Parsing xml file with libxml2

Tags: c, xml, parsing, libxml2

I have been trying to parse an xml document by using **libxml2**, and I am using **Dev c++** for compilation. I couldn't figure out how to utilize `libxml2/parser.h`? I am getting the error

```
no such file or directory
```

(I am using **windows**)

Comment: you are getting the error by .. doing what? calling which function call?

Comment: I cannot compile the source file

Comment: so your question is not about xml or libxml2 or xyz but "how to compile a file with a c-compiler"? then you should give information about how you invoke which c-compiler and where the c-code is.

Comment: please show us some code (your compile-command f.e. the -I includepath and the line of your #include "libxml\parser.h".

Comment: windows and "/" in path? is that okay? in thee olde dayes, it was a "\" for path.

Comment: @PeterMiehle I think Windows accepts slashes as path delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

The libxml2 bundle normally is not installed into a standard path (under unix f.e. /usr/include), so you have to tell the compiler/IDE where you installed the include and the library (f.e. /home/include). In modern IDEs this can be achieved just by dragging/dropping the library into the project. In other environments you have to adjust your makefile or you system (environment variable) to point the include-path to your libxml2-directorys include path (-I with gcc) and library path (-L). In your IDE you may have a option/project settings to do so.